# re-use MS office licence?

Tags: microsoft-office, license

I bought a new computer and on my old computer that still working I have MS office Professional Plus 2007 (official/legal). I would like to remove it from my old computer and install on the new one. I have two problems :

- My new computer do not read CD.
- I lost the paper where was written the serial number. (But I think I was able to found it thanks to licenceCrawler)

Is there a way to directly migrate ? What would be the best method ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you try to install it one the new computer?

Comment: Sometimes, when I have done this, I get an error message saying that it has been installed too many times. If I remember correctly, it tells you how to contact Microsoft, which you should do.

Comment: @Mawg, no I can't because the new computer do not read CD/DVD...

Comment: Given how old  Office 2007 is you might want to also consider libreoffice which is free and has many newer features.

Comment: @cybernard, I'm already using libreOffice, but I need to maintain MSoffice to share documents with colleagues. There is a compatibility problem between both to maintain editable mathematical equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office 2007 Professional Plus is not available for public download,
and is not available via Microsoft Store, because it is a Volume License edition only.

You will need to contact your company/organization entitlement/benefit administrator
(the person who has access to your company/organization Volume Licensing agreement).

The bottom line is that Professional Plus was Volume License only.
You need to log into the VLSC to get the software.
If you don't have the account information for your company's VLSC account,
you need to find the licensing document which will have your
Agreement/Authorization information and you can then create a new VLSC account
and associate the Agreement with the new account.

If you can't find your VL documents, the VLSC support folks or your
original reseller can look up your company information and provide you with
that information.

Answer (score 1):

As you have indicated that your old computer is still working, you can register your software with Microsoft (if you have not yet done so) by signing into your Microsoft account.

You should be able to locate the product listing in your account, along with a link to download the product independently of a storage medium. If you don't see it on the list, there will also be a location into which you can register the software.

It should also be possible to install the download on the new machine prior to removing it from the old computer to ensure that the installation goes smoothly. Once installed on the new machine, uninstall it from the older one to maintain license integrity.

Answer (score -1):

For what it is worth, I generally buy MS Office & Windows licenses - legally - on eBay for less than $10. This might be your simplest solution.

Here's a search https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=ms+office&_sacat=0&_sop=15

Currently, Office 365 is available for $2.68 and Office 2016 for $1.26

Comment: Please refrain from adding eBay links to your answers. Apart from looking kind of spammy, these will not be permanent. I'd recommend telling the users how to find what they're looking for instead.

Comment: I have removed the links to the current offerings, but left the link to the search. Is that OK? Everyone I tell about this at work is always surprised, so I thought that I would share. I also have Visual Studio Enterprise edition for less than $10. Of course, it's not just Microsoft products that are available this way.

Comment: I doubt if these are legitimate licenses. My guess is that it's one product key sold over and over. At some point too many people install Office using the same key in a short timeframe and it gets marked as suspicious. It's also possible that these are education licenses that can be revoked anytime.

Comment: What happens is that when businesses sell PCs, they are bought by companies who recycle parts, or sell them on. While doing so, they scan the registry for license keys. It is legal to re-sell those. I doubt if eBay would tolerate so many such sellers if it were no legal. I have bought a few dozen by now and never had a problem.

Comment: See https://brodies.com/binformed/legal-updates/european-court-confirms-the-right-to-resell-used-software-licences and https://www.quora.com/How-can-eBay-powersellers-sell-Windows-software-licence-keys-so-cheap and Google for more.

Comment: Well, I just clicked the Quora link. The first answer doesn't help much. 2nd one says these are "cracked" keys, whatever that means. 3rd one says that either these are volume license keys incorrectly sold as retail/OEM despite MS license forbidding that outside of EU or they come from credit card fraud. Not really reassuring.

Comment: Yes, I read it too. I just wanted to give a balanced view. Maybe he is US based, whereas the first link makes it very clear that license selling it legal in the EU. I Guess the OP  should do due diligence and find out what is legal in his jurisdiction.  https://law.stackexchange.com/  might help. I imagine that it was you who downvoted me, but really your comments are "I doubt" and "I think", whereas I can back up my answer with a legal answer

Comment: No, I didn't downvote you. Legal stuff aside, these licenses tend to suddenly become invalid. I bought one myself some time ago and based on this experience I can't recommend it. I was never able to activate it over the Internet and over-the-phone activation is dead since last year or so, so I basically can't use a product that I paid for and Microsoft didn't see a penny from it too.

Comment: Thanks for not downvoting :-) I upvoted your comment ;-)  Sorry to hear bout your bad experience. As I said, I have bought a few dozen by now and never had a problem. Maybe just luck of the draw? At least it's too much money lost if it happened (cold comfort, I know).  I also use sites like Kinguin, although that's more game oriented. I never had a problem there either.